# How to perform validation using jquery.validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to use jquery.validate to validate some fields in a jquery modal dialog.  To practice I thought I would create a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgreer5050/5JYa3/) to make sure my syntax is correct.  I'm missing something, hopefully someone can help.

Here is my simple form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="field1" />
<input type="text" name="field2" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$("#submitEdit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
Validate();
});

function Validate()
{       
    $("#frmEdit").validate({
        rules: {
            QtyOnHand: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            QtyOnHand: {
                required: 'Qty Required'
            }

        }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fE9Nu/)

Just keep

```
$("#frmEdit").validate({//this will validate you don't need call validate function
    rules: {
        QtyOnHand: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        QtyOnHand: {
            required: 'Qty Required'
        }
    }
});
```

---

Remove

```
$("#submitEdit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();//stopping validation to occur
}
```

[**Problem Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fE9Nu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
      <input type="text" name="field1" />
      <input type="text" name="field2" />
      <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

JS:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                required: 'field1 Required'
            },
            field2: {
                required: 'field2 Required'
            }

        }
  });
```

check
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JYa3/1/)